# How to extract specific cell (column of cells) from mysql, do "something" on it and save in the same place?

Tags: php, mysql, cell

I have a phpbb forum 3.0.5 (using php and mysql).
I would like to extract only "topics" and "posts" cells from the database and translate content with google translate and then save (rewrite) translated content to the same place in database. Can this be done?

If not, can you tell me how to export only specific table content?

example below:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
a b c d e f 
g h i j k l
```

I would like to export only column 5 with all values (e, k,...) without sql specific tags - just the text.

Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following query on the table in question to get out only the required column:

```
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `column_name` FROM `table_name` LIMIT 0, 30 ";
```

This will give you the requested column - from all the content in the table.
you can than go through the results, convert them and reinsert them into the database with this query:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `database_name`.`table_name` SET `column` = 'new translated content\' WHERE `table_nane`.`id` = the_proper_id;";
```

So basically your pulling out all of the values that need to be changed, going through them one by one, translating and updating them in the database.

Comment: Thank you for help.
I am really new to programming so can you help me just a bit more:

The "structure" of the base is something like these:

-base name
---table with posts
------column where only posts (text) are

How can I grab this data and display it in readable output?

Thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 0):

To select one column, you do the following:

```
SELECT columnName FROM tableName
```

You then manipulate the data as required and save it:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id,columnName FROM tableName"); // You need ID field for reference
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) {
   $field = $row["columnName"];
   // Do Something with the Field Data
   // ...
   // ...

   // Update the Table with new values
   $update = "UPDATE tableName SET columnName = '".$field."' WHERE id = '".$row['id']."'");
   mysql_query($update); // This update the field with what you set in "$field"
}
```

// LEARN MORE:

[SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

[UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

Answer (score 0):

To be ore specific:
1. start a database connection.
2. get all the information out of the table using the query I specified earlier:

```
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `column_name` FROM `table_name` ";
```

To run this query do something like:

```
  $query_results = $database_connection->query($sql);//this will run the query and get all the results, check to make sure it all worked:
 if(!$query_results){
 echo "There was a problem: ".$db_connection->error;
} else { 
//the query worked so this is what we do
//get the number of results
$result_number = $query_results->num_rows;//the number of results
$result_info = $query_results->fetch_assoc();//getting the information from the first result
//looping through:
for($i = 0; $i < $result_number; $i++){
$value_to_convert = $result_info['needed_column'];
//do what ever you want to the value_to_convert - also - needed_column is the name of the column you need.
//insert the new value back into the database:
$sql = "UPDATE `database_name`.`table_name` SET `column` = 'new translated content\' WHERE ``table_nane`.`id` = the_proper_id;";
//run it:
$update_query = $db_connection->query($sql);
//check like before
if(!$update_query){


 echo "There was a problem updating: ".$db_connection->error
} 
//get the next result:
$result_info = $query_results->fetch_assoc();//getting the information from the first result
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you again!!
I have now managed to export only that column of data - thanks to YOU!
Still, I get some "overhead" in exported SQL file, but it is minimal. I have translated the content. 

How can I now import the same SQL file to database? How do I update the column using SQL file (overwrite)?

Thanks again!!

Comment: Just as I said in the example above - using the update Query - specifying the ID of the row you want to update. just look at the example, specifically the $update_query. Please don't forget to rate or mark as answered.

Comment: Ok, I've managed to translate the content and import the file again but 2 problems occur:
1st problem is that I export text in english and then translate it to spannish and mysql rejects importing because of syntax problem. I guess it has something to do with UTF8 format? 

2nd problem is that when I export column and then import it again it mixes up the order. I would like to import to the same place in the same order as it was exported. I hope you know what I mean.

please help me on this issue and then I will rate you max poinst ;)
thanks in advance!